# Do I really need to convert images into base64 format before uploading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, strapi

When working with React and Express.js, it is recommended to convert image blob files into base64 format. Is there any specific reason why we need to do it this way?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert it to base64, actually it adds 33% size overhead so I believe it is not recommended way to upload data to the backend. Use http multipart instead.